# prolog list path and avoid certain route

Tags: path, prolog

I have a list of data

```
city(portsmouth,london).
city(london,bristol).
city(portsmouth,plymouth).
city(plymouth,london).
city(london,plymouth).
city(london,birmingham).
city(birmingham,bristol).
```

I'm using a method which is

```
 ?-op(150,xfy,pathto).
 ?-op(150,xfy,avoid).
 X pathto Y:- city(X,Y).
```

and not so sure can be use like

```
X pathto Y avoid Z:-
    findall(Path,avoid_country(X,Y,Z,Path),Paths),write(Paths),nl.  

avoid_path(Start, End, Avoid,[]) :- 
    country(Start, End).

avoid_path(Start,End,Avoid,[Path|Result]):-
    city(Start,Path),
    Path\== Avoid,
    avoid_path(Path, End,Avoid, Result).
```

it actually works perfectly without the avoids thing as well as the Path\== Avoid,

the error result is

```
   | ?- portsmouth to bristol avoid birmingham.
   Error 1, Backtrack Stack Full, Trying city/2
```

it should be [[london],[plymouth,london]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so : first you got a loop in your facts : (london, plymouth) and (plymouth, london). That means that any attempt of backtracking will never end.
Then I'm not sure that you can use 2 operators this way, but since I'm not sure, other people will be more insightful on the matter :)
I took this convention : portsmouth to bristol-[london, birmingham] means from portsmouth to bristol avoiding london and birmingham (I took this convention not to manage the operators question), here is a working code that keeps track of visited cities to avoid infinite possibilities :

```
city(portsmouth,london).
city(london,bristol).
city(portsmouth,plymouth).
city(plymouth,london).
city(london,plymouth).
city(london,birmingham).
city(birmingham,bristol).

:- op(150, xfy, to).

Start to End-Avoid :-
    findall(Waypoint, get_waypoints(Start, End, [Start], Avoid, Waypoint), Waypoints),
    !,
    write(Waypoints).
Start to End :-
    findall(Waypoint, get_waypoints(Start, End, [Start], [], Waypoint), Waypoints),
    write(Waypoints).

get_waypoints(Start, End, _Visited, _Avoid, []) :- 
    city(Start, End).
get_waypoints(Start, End, Visited, Avoid, [Waypoint|Result]) :-
    city(Start, Waypoint),
```

don't go through cities to avoid...

```
    \+ member(Waypoint, Avoid),
```

this check allows us not to fall into loops. This way, backtracking ends.

```
    \+ member(Waypoint, Visited),
    get_waypoints(Waypoint, End, [Waypoint|Visited], Avoid, Result).
```

Comment: Thanks but may i know how the Start to End-Avoid :- works? Is 
?- portsmouth to bristol-birmingham or other command? Sorry but i never seen any like this

Comment: well basicly it's just a convention I took to pack 2 arguments in one since the to operator has only 2 arguments. But as I said I'm not knowledgeable about operator definition so there might be a way to make it work with to and avoid to get to 3 arguments. So, to come back to the explanation about End-Avoid, if you use "x to y", it won't unify with "Start to End-Avoid" so the second clause will be used, if you use "x to y-z" it will unify with "Start to End-Avoid" with Start = x End = y and Avoid = Z and therefore pass z as argument Avoid to the get_waypoints predicate.

Comment: and the syntax is ?- Start to End-[Avoid1, Avoid2,...]

Comment: did you specify [birmingham] if you used my code or only birmingham ? Because if you don't want a list of cities to avoid (the case in my code) you can change the line \+ member(Waypoint, Avoid), to \+ Waypoint = Avoid and it will work

Comment: yes it works, actually my page did not refreshed so i've posted up which after i saw your comment. Also I've used to predicate to somewhere and has similar function and prolog confused. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You facts contain those two:

```
city(plymouth,london).
city(london,plymouth).
```

and your code (which contains some inconsistencies) does not check whether a city has already been visited. This will make `findall/3` collect all possible routes [london],[plymouth,london],[plymouth,london,plymouth,london],... , which will sooner or later lead to memory exhaustion.